# Подскажите паттерн проектирования для классов с единым функционалом

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, design

Есть такой набор классов:

```
class A extends ParentA {
    public function someFn1() { $a = 1 + 3; echo $a; parent::someFn1() }
    public function someFn2() { $b = rand(10); echo $b; parent::someFn2() }
}

class B extends ParentB {
    public function someFn1() { $a = 1 + 3; echo $a; parent::someFn1() }
    public function someFn2() { $b = rand(10); echo $b; parent::someFn2() }
}

class C extends ParentC {
    public function someFn1() { $a = 1 + 3; echo $a; parent::someFn1() }
    public function someFn2() { $b = rand(10); echo $b; parent::someFn2() }
}

class D extends ParentD {
    public function someFn1() { $a = 1 + 3; echo $a; parent::someFn1() }
    public function someFn2() { $b = rand(10); echo $b; parent::someFn2() }
}
```

и так  далее.
При этом:
**ParentA ... ParentD** являются наследниками класса **Parent**

и **A ... D** методы someFn1, someFn1 и прочие  имеют с точки зрения кода идентичный функционал. Но реализация в родительских классах различается.

Сам класс Parent:

```
class Parent {
    abstract public function someFn1();
    abstract public function someFn2();
}
```

Пример класса ParentA:

```
class ParentA {
    public function someFn1() { echo "ParentA fn1" };
    public function someFn2() { echo "ParentA fn2" };
}
```

Функционал приведен только в качестве примера.

**Вопросы**:

как реорганизовать классы **A-D**, без изменения классов **Parent**, **ParentA
-ParentD**, чтобы избежать множественных копипастов.

В общем случае задача такая: имя класса одно, но наследоваться он должен от различных классов.

Пример:

```
class SomeName extends ParentA {
    public function someFn1() { ... };
    public function someFn2() { ... };
}
```

где наследник **ParentA** меняется на другой. Однако это в идеальном случае.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться миксином. Т.е. вынести some-методы в отдельный trait-класс

```
trait someFunctions {
    public static function someFn1() { $a = 1 + 3; echo $a; parent::someFn1(); }
    public static function someFn2() { $b = rand(10); echo $b; parent::someFn2(); }
}
```

После чего подмешать его в каждый из классов, где необходимы функции `someFn1()` и `someFn2()`.

```
class A extends ParentA {
    use someFunctions;
}

class B extends ParentB {
    use someFunctions;
}

class C extends ParentC {
    use someFunctions;
}

class D extends ParentD {
    use someFunctions;
}
```